# How to check if parameter is coming from FormBody or FormUri?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have created common ActionFilter to validate all the HTTP Requests before calling ActionMethod.

I want to filter out parameters coming from FormBody. By default all my request content-type is application/json.

This will enable me to call JSON Format(Not schema) validator to respond with correct error message to client.

```
public class QueryStringParameterValidatorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var args = actionContext.ActionArguments;
        var parameters = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();//I want to filter out parameters coming from Form Body
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your Request parameters while executing this code in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Then add this line:

```
foreach (var p in parameters)
{
    bool HasFromBodyAttribute = p.GetCustomAttributes<FromBodyAttribute>().Count > 0;   

    if(HasFromBodyAttribute)
    {
        // code here
    }

}
```